# SQL Syntax on stored procedures

Tags: sql, mysql

ERROR 1064 (42000) in main.mysql: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

I have this code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE solution()
SELECT name
FROM leaderboard
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 3;
END
```

The code doesnt go through

Comment: I believe there should be a `BEGIN` before `SELECT`.

Comment: Or, when you have only 1 statement in your procedure, you do not need an `END`, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/cHNSFKC-

Comment: But the original worked too!  , The error just is about the `END` which if not recognized because a missing `BEGIN` (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/-fEH0QKP

Comment: That's why you always need to provide FULL error messages when asking on stackoverflow.com, and not vague statement like "The code doesnt go through" .  